# Advanced Custom Fields acf_form - Filtering Post Object Fields (meta_query)?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have post types "Clients", "Projects", and "Tasks". Each Project is linked to a Client using an ACF "Post Object" field.

I have a front end "Task" editing form rendered via the acf_form() function:

```
acf_form( 
    array(
        'fields' => array( 'status', 'client', 'project') ,
        'post_title' => true,
        'post_content' => true,
    ) 
);
```

However, the "Projects" selection control populates all projects in the database. Is it possible for it to only get the Projects that relate to the selected Client? I don't see anything in the documentation about passing parameters into the field list, etc. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/

Comment: You can write the input field by hand `<input ... />` with getting the data you want in a variable first and place it in this input (select options or whatever). Then put the input field code inside `html_after_fields` or `html_before_fields`

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is a better option than the separate form I was going to make. I just thought there might be a more tightly integrated method and I have been trying to not "custom-do" things when a proper solution already exists. Cheers!